# Call elements inside list of list in python

Tags: python, list, nested

My question is, 
if I have a list like this:

```
List = [[0, "hi", "bye"], 
        [3, 5, 6, 8], 
        [[8, 9, 0, "el"], [5, 8, 6]],
        [0, 5, 9] ]
```

is there a sintactic way to call element "el" inside this this, I imagine I would go for a function like List.indexdepth( 2, 0, 3 ) by calling the index inside each list..like a cartesian system but with N dimension, because we can have N number of lists inside one another, so the number of index coordinates will be equal to list nesting depth.... I think of this method because is a better way to call elements from list that will be changing len(), so it's more problable that this index depth number describing an element position will not change............
well, but the core of my question is if I have a big list with nested lists, how can I call an element with a short code.

Comment: `List[2][0][3]` is about as short as you can get without defining a function to do that for you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call a list 'List' as `'list'` (small l) is already a reserved object type, and could be confusing. Anyway. The easiest way is:

`List[2][0][3]` in this case would be the index for "el", and you couldn't get much simpler or shorter than that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! , exactly what I was looking for!